# What is the best to extend functionality of a Library class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a library code that provides class and that class is expected to be a subclass of my frameworks classes.

Now I want to extend one of the functionalities of a library class method, here I can think of 2 approaches:

1. create a new class with subclass library class then override library class method in a new class
2. create Mixins override the functionality of the library class method and inherit that as well
   Here is a coded way of my above 2 theoretical approaches.

**approach 1:**

```py
class Library:

    def method_one(self):
        return {"method_one": "one"}

    def method_two(self):
        return {"method_two": "two"}


class FrameworkOne(Library):
    def method_one(self):
        method = super().method_one()
        method["label"] = self.__class__.__name__
        return method
        
        
class FrameworkTwo(Library):
    def method_one(self):
        method = super().method_one()
        method["label"] = self.__class__.__name__
        return method
```

**approach 2:**

```py
class MixinFramework:
    def method_one(self):
        method = super().method_one()
        method["label"] = self.__class__.__name__
        return method


class FrameworkOne(MixinFramework, Library):
    pass


class FrameworkTwo(MixinFramework, Library):
    pass
```

another way I can think of is to create another Baseclass which will inherit Library class and override `method_one` in Base class and inherit Baseclass in all Framework classes instead of Library class

approach one seems to code redundancy issue and approach two seems to me like narrow down
is there any better approach or a decorator way that I can put on to each class where I want to extend the functionality of `method_one`
Please suggest.

Comment: what is the point of `method_two()` ?

Comment: In your example, the `Library` class is not a subclass, but a superclass of your `Framework*` classes, contradictory to your written requirement.

Comment: @sudden_appearance method_two() is another method is just for an example

Comment: @RichardNeumann yes Library class is superclass always.

Comment: If the second codeblock works, I would go with that since it's DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) code

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes second code block works fine but what if we wanted to `method_two` functionality to be extended in  FrameworkTwo and FrameworkThree

Comment: can we achieve this by adding a decorator on Framework classes